# CSS: changing child padding affects parent size (with box-sizing: border-box)

Tags: css, layout, padding

I'm using react-bootstrap in my application. Consider such layout:

```js
let changed = false
document.querySelector("#addPadding").onclick = () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.input')
  elem.style.paddingRight = changed ? 0 : '2rem'
  changed = !changed
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  /* Width and height are actually unknown,
     set only for presentation purposes */
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.otherStuff {
  background: aqua;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.form {
  background: palevioletred;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 2rem;
  min-width: 40%;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: .2rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="addPadding">Add padding</button>
<article class="body">
  <div class="otherStuff">Some content of unknown size</div>
  <div class="form">
    <input class="input">
  </div>
</article>
```

If you run the snippet, you'll notice, that each time the input's padding changes, so does the width of the parent element. Also that doesn't happen with all viewport sizes: for example it works just fine if `.body` has a width of `400px` or `800px`. Padding size is changed internally by bootstrap, so I can't really influence it. Even if I could, that would break other stuff. What can I do to prevent parent forom stretching here?

Comment: The parent stretching is an effect of the article being a flexbox element. If you don’t want this, then you would need to forbid the flex items from growing; not sure how well that would work here since you have only a min-width of 30% set for the first one, and 40% for the second - that is kinda “vague” to begin with. You should give us a clear specification of what needs to be achieved here first of all.

Comment: @04FS, well, the only thing I want is to make `.form` persist its width whatsoever. I agree, dimensions are kinda vague. If I find no solution to this at all, I could of course set exact `width` to the `.form`, but I'd like to avoid it, because then I will need breakpoints for different screen sizes. Should I clarify anything else?

Comment: How and when does bootstrap change the padding for this input field? You said you can’t change it (to be seen) - but do you _want_ this effect in the first place?

Comment: @04FS, yes, I want this effect to be there. It happens, when the input data is invalid, then it adds a cross icon as well as the padding, so that it doesn't overlap input text.

Comment: Then I don’t think you can solve this using CSS alone, while keeping the widths of both elements somewhat variable at the same time.

Comment: @04FS, ok, I can live with it. But can you explain, why it works fine when width of `.body` is more than `800px`? It would be nice, if I could reliably use this effect to ensure dynamic width for large screens

Comment: Probably somehow due to the combination of flexbox and specifying min-widths only. With the margins/padding of 2rem thrown in, there’s probably a point somewhere where that “fits” into the prescribed min-widths, whereas with smaller container size it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `width:100%` consider the input as a flex item with `flex-grow:1`

```js
let changed = false
document.querySelector("#addPadding").onclick = () => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.input')
  elem.style.paddingRight = changed ? 0 : '2rem'
  changed = !changed
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  /* Width and height are actually unknown,
     set only for presentation purposes */
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.otherStuff {
  background: aqua;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.form {
  background: palevioletred;
  height: 75%;
  padding: 2rem;
  min-width: 40%;
  display:flex;
}

.input {
  flex-grow:1;
  width:0;
  align-self:flex-start;
  padding: .2rem;
  
  background:yellow content-box; /* To illustrate */
}
```

```html
<button id="addPadding">Add padding</button>
<article class="body">
  <div class="otherStuff">Some content of unknown size</div>
  <div class="form">
    <input class="input">
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: I'd love to, but, as I said, I'm using bootstrap, which sets all styles by itself. Even if I customize them, there's a big change it will break the rest of the layout

Comment: @AlexChashin bootstrap doesn't set the styles for you. Boostrap offer you styles to use and you don't need to customize anything. You simply need to correctly use them. Share your code with bootstrap and I will update my answer with bootstrap